# How to avoid "Invalid Trajectory (cost: -1.000000)" in DWA Local Planner?

Tags: navigation, differential-drive, dwa, planner, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am using DWA to drive a differential robot around. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS Hydro.

In general, the robot navigates well. However, sometimes when I send it to tight spots, I receive the following warnings:

```
[ WARN] [1435079055.081046415]: Invalid Trajectory 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.822608, cost: -1.000000
[ WARN] [1435079056.578828210]: Invalid Trajectory 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.931650, cost: -1.000000
[ WARN] [1435079058.079198312]: Invalid Trajectory 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.850638, cost: -1.000000
[ WARN] [1435079058.580604641]: Invalid Trajectory 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, cost: -1.000000
[ WARN] [1435079060.483851910]: Invalid Trajectory 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.400000, cost: -1.000000
```

While receiving these warnings, the robot stands still, and eventually starts doing recovery behaviors, aborting most of the time afterwards.

My questions:

- What is causing these invalid trajectories with cost: -1?
- How can I avoid them?

Below, my "base_local_planner_params.yaml" file:

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 0.8        
  min_vel_x: 0.2
  max_vel_y: 0.0        
  min_vel_y: 0.0  
  max_vel_theta: 2.0
  min_vel_theta: -2.0 
  min_in_place_vel_theta : 0.65
  escape_vel: -0.1

  acc_lim_theta: 3.2    
  acc_lim_x: 2.5        
  acc_lim_y: 0.0                       

  holonomic_robot: false

  sim_time: 1.5
  sim_granularity: 0.025 
  angular_sim_granularity: 0.025
  vx_samples: 5                         
  vy_samples: 0
  vtheta_samples: 20
  meter_scoring: false                 

  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.2              
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25              
  latch_xy_goal_tolerance: false        
  gdist_scale: 0.5                      
  pdist_scale: 0.7                      
  occdist_scale: 0.02        

  dwa: true
```

Here is a video of the robot's behavior:
https://youtu.be/Y-zro-sXO-o

Let me know if further details are necessary.
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211961/how-to-avoid-%22invalid-trajectory-(cost:--1.000000)%22-in-dwa-local-planner?/) by [DavidPortugal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1522/davidportugal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 349 on 2015-06-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-06-25**:
How are you specifying the footprint?

**Comment by [DavidPortugal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1522/davidportugal/) on 2015-06-25**:
Here it is:
footprint: [[0.15,0.22],[0.15,-0.22],[-0.55,-0.22],[-0.55,0.22]]
it's a rectangle around the robot.

**Comment by [DavidPortugal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1522/davidportugal/) on 2015-06-30**:
I've been playing around with the vx_samples and vtheta_samples lately, but still without success.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-03-03**:
Hi David (Portugal), did you end up finding a way to make DWA "behave"? Thanks!

**Comment by [DavidPortugal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1522/davidportugal/) on 2016-03-04**:
Unfortunately no @spmaniato. The problem wasn't critical, and the robot would recover eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It means that it can't find any valid plan. Invalid plans have negative costs.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidPortugal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1522/davidportugal/) on 2015-06-24**:
Yes, I am aware of that, thanks.
The issue is: What is causing the generation of invalid plans and how can I avoid it?
Do you see anything in the parameters that should not be there and might cause this?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-06-24**:
To figure that out, you need to be more explicit about what the tight spot actually looks like in relation to your robot.

**Comment by [DavidPortugal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1522/davidportugal/) on 2015-06-25**:
Thank you David, I've added a video showing the robot's behavior in the original question.

**Comment by [SH_Developer](https://answers.ros.org/users/26427/sh_developer/) on 2017-07-04**:
Hi i m facing the same problem! Did you find any solution

**Comment by [KevWal](https://answers.ros.org/users/142877/kevwal/) on 2023-08-10**:
I have the same issue too, no solution yet

**Comment by [KevWal](https://answers.ros.org/users/142877/kevwal/) on 2023-08-10**:
I have found, that depending on the planner in use, this is what it means in the code.

If dwa:

```
 ROS_WARN("Invalid Trajectory %f, %f, %f, cost: %f", vel_samples[0], vel_samples[1], vel_samples[2], cost);
```

or if trajectory_planner:

```
ROS_WARN("Invalid Trajectory %f, %f, %f, cost: %f", vx_samp, vy_samp, vtheta_samp, cost);
```